# Using Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability

Customers arrive at a checkout counter in a department score according to a Poisson distribution at an average of seven per hour. During a given hour, what are the probabilities that:

a.) no more than three customers arrive?
b.) at least two customers arrive?
c.) exactly five customers arrive?

Poisons Formula: $\frac{X^y}{y!}e^{-X}$

My answers:

a.) $1 - (P(Y=3) + P(Y=2)+P(Y=1)+P(Y=0))$
Basically I just use the Poisons formula and substitution $y$ and the $X$ as $7$.

b.) $1 - (P(Y=1) + P(Y=0))$

c.) $P(Y=0)+P(Y=1)+P(Y=2)+P(Y=3)+P(Y=4)+P(Y=5)$

Is this correct? I am not really good at this stuff.Thanks.

Comment: Your answer an a) corresponds with 'more than $3$'. Your answer on b) is correct. Your answer on c) corresponds with 'no more than $5$'.

Comment: @drhab for a.) should it be just P(Y=3) nad for 5 it should just be P(Y=5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poisson Distribution is given by $$f(y) = \frac{\lambda^ye^{-\lambda}}{y!}$$

For part **A** the Question asks for the probability that **NO MORE THAN THREE** arrive. So that is simply $$P(0 ~~arrive) + P(1 ~~arrives) + P(2 ~~arrive) + P(3 ~~arrive)$$ What you've solved for instead is $$P(more ~~than ~~3 ~~customers ~~arrive)$$ Get rid of the *1 minus* and you're good to go. Just plug 7 hours in for $\lambda$ and each of your $Y$ values in for $y$

---

Part **B** looks good to me.

---

For part **C**, all you want to solve for is $P(Y=5)$, you don't care about the other terms. So again, just solve using the above distribution function (plug $5$ in for $y$ and $7$ in for $\lambda$)